# Show Header Footer and cell in single cell?

Tags: ios, swift, header, tableview, footer

[image: Screenshot to do task]

Please suggest me can i do this inside single card with cell header cell footer and cell.

Comment: No, you can't because for header and footer have specific delegate methods to show view or show cell

Comment: You can design the cell with all header, footer and content as separate views and show/hide these views dynamically.

Comment: but its quite difficult for due to dynamic labels and dynamic height for view..!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that you don't have any header and footer to your table view.

- **Create 3 types of cell i.e answer cell, question cell, and solution cell.**
- **Design your cells as per your UI requirement.**
- **Create the data source for the question, answer and solution cell.**

In TableView's Delegate method of CellForRowAtIndexPath Implement the following code.

```
  enum CellType : String {
       case answer
       case solution
       case question
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cellType = arrayDataSource[indexPath.item]

    switch cellType {

    case .answer:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "answerCell",
                                                      for: indexPath) as! AnswerCell
        return cell

    case .solution:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "solutionCell",
                                                      for: indexPath) as! SolutionCell
        return cell

    case .question:
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "questionCell",
                                                      for: indexPath) as! QuestionCell
       return cell

    }

}
```

- Create your data source according to cell type.
- Manage height for a row in table view's delegate method. Use UITableViewAutomaticDimension introduced in the iOS 9.

The following link to understand automatic row height :

https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: But my question is how can i show them in a single card..?

Comment: @GurpreetSingh I don't think you can do it with a single card.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think of them as footer and header. Just top, middle and bottom parts of the cell. Then you can build a complex view containing these three parts.
You can implement 3 of them as different custom views, and the cell will just be a container for all of them.